# React-bootstrap-table - set maxLength for text filter inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react-bootstrap-table library (first version) and would like to set the maximum length for all filter inputs in my table component. Is there such option or I need some query selector to do it for me?  I can't find anything like this in the docs.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**One way** how to do it (not the one which is "react way") is , as you assumed, with query selector e.g:

```
document.querySelectorAll('<filter-row-classname> input')
    .forEach(filter => filter.setAttribute('maxlength',5))
```

< filter-row-classname > - in react-table it is *.-filters*

I would suggest **second way**:

You can define you own columns :

```
const columns = [{
    Cell: JSX | string | function,
    Header: JSX | string | function,
    Filter: JSX | function
    Footer: JSX | string function,
    <much more - see documentation>
}]
```

So actually you can do following within columns  :

```
Filter: onChange => (
            <input 
                onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}
                maxLength="your_value"
            />
```

here is edited code - check "last-name" :
[working example with maxlength attribute](https://codesandbox.io/s/reacttablecustomfiltering-vqbco)

Regards